# Servidor não atualiza a página após alteração dinâmica

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, app

Gero uma página através de:

```
app.get('/conteudo', (req, res) => {
    res.send(conteudojson);                        
}).
```

Dinamicamente, o `conteudojson` é alterado e listado novamente o "/conteudo":

```
app.get('/conteudo', (req, res) => {
    res.send(conteudojson);                        
}).
```

Porém, ao acessar "/conteudo", é mostrado somente a primeira interface gerada e não a alterada com alteração do `conteudojson`. 
Somente depois que eu paro o servidor com <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> e inicio novamente o servidor que a alteração do `conteudojson` é listada em "/conteudo".

Abaixo o código:

```
const editarIndicador = (dados, app) => {
    let key = dados.chave
    console.log('Dentro de Edição')
    firebird.attach(optionsInd, function(err, db) {
        var optionsIndicador = {
            "chart": {
                "title": `${dados.editarTitulo}`,
                "subtitle": `${dados.editarSubtitulo}`
            },
            "width": dados.editarLargura,
            "height": dados.editarAltura   }
        let opcoes = JSON.stringify(optionsIndicador)
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            console.log('Erro:', err)
        }
        let SQL = `update
               TBL_INDICADORES
               set DESC_INDICADOR ='${dados.editarDescInd}' ,
               MODELO ='${dados.editarModeloIndicador}',
               BUSCARDADOS ='${dados.editarDados}',
               OPTIONSIND ='${opcoes}'
               where KEY = ${key}`
        console.log('SQL: ', SQL)
        db.query(SQL, null, function(err, result) {
            db.query(`SELECT * FROM TBL_INDICADORES WHERE KEY=${key}`, function(err, result) {
                console.log('Ultimo registro Alterado', result);
                function fx(v) { return v }              
                app.get('/indicadores', (req, res) => {                 
                    res.send(result);
                })
                db.detach();
            });
        });
    });
    return true
}
```

No console, é mostrado que foi alterado o conteúdo passado pela *SQL*. 
Porém, com `res.send(result)` não lança o novo conteúdo em "/indicadores", que possui o conteúdo da primeira listagem.

---

Abaixo o código:

```
const editarIndicador = (dados, app) => {
    let key = dados.chave
    console.log('Dentro de Edição')
    firebird.attach(optionsInd, function(err, db) {
        var optionsIndicador = {
            "chart": {
                "title": `${dados.editarTitulo}`,
                "subtitle": `${dados.editarSubtitulo}`
            },
            "width": dados.editarLargura,
            "height": dados.editarAltura   }
        let opcoes = JSON.stringify(optionsIndicador)
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            console.log('Erro:', err)
        }
        let SQL = `update
               TBL_INDICADORES
               set DESC_INDICADOR ='${dados.editarDescInd}' ,
               MODELO ='${dados.editarModeloIndicador}',
               BUSCARDADOS ='${dados.editarDados}',
               OPTIONSIND ='${opcoes}'
               where KEY = ${key}`
        console.log('SQL: ', SQL)
        db.query(SQL, null, function(err, result) {
            db.query(`SELECT * FROM TBL_INDICADORES WHERE KEY=${key}`, function(err, result) {
                console.log('Ultimo registro Alterado', result);
                function fx(v) { return v }              
                app.get('/indicadores', (req, res) => {                 
                    res.send(result);
                })
                db.detach();
            });
        });
    });
    return true
}
```

Comment: Só com esse código que postou não tem como ajudar.

Comment: Entendo LeAndrade. Postarei todo o código abaixo. Mas a minha dúvida é quando utilizo nodejs com expresse e lanço um res.send() há como sobrepor o que foi gerado pelo send()?

Comment: Amigo por sua pergunta ser muito vaga, penso que o efeito que voce quer é que quando voce muda seu arquivo o servidor mude tambem na url, para isso voce pode usar a ferramenta [nodemon](https://nodemon.io). Basta seguir a documentação e toda vez que seu sistema tiver alteração nos arquivos o servidor vai ser recarregado.

Comment: você está usando uma função, precisa dar o return, não é isso?

Comment: Não precisa de return. Ele seta no app a rota. quando uso                 ´`app.get('/indicadores', (req, res) => {                 
                    res.send(result);
                })`´

Comment: Cara tá bem estranho esse seu código pra falar verdade, vc pega o json atualizado de onde? E quando dá **res.send(conteudojson)** vc simplesmente joga na tela o json, nã está dando para entender.

Answer (score 0):

Bastou usar o nodemon para atualização dinâmica da página.